# combination with repetition or permutation $n$=5

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have 5 types of symptoms, I want to know all kind of combinations a patient could have:

The set is $(vomit, excrement, urine, dizzyness, convulsion)$

As patient can show only one, or even 5 of them I am listing them as:

So

## Possibilities with one symptom

```
vomit
excrement
urine
dizzyness
convulsion
```

## Possibilities with two symptoms

```
vomit and excrement
vomit and urine
vomit and dizzyness
vomit and convulsion
excrement and urine
excrement and dizzyness
excrement and convulsion
urine and dizzyness
urine and convulsion
```

## Possibilities with three symptoms

```
vomit, excrement and urine
vomit, excrement and dizzyness
vomit, excrement and convulsion
excrement, urine and dizzyness
excrement, urine and convulsion
urine, dizzyness and convulsion
```

## Possibilities with four symptoms

```
vomit, excrement, urine and dizzyness
vomit, excrement, urine and convulsion
```

## Possibilities with all five symptoms

```
vomit, excrement, urine, dizzyness and  convulsion
```

What formula is being used here ? as it is not $C{{n}\choose{r}}$.

Could you explain it a little ?

So I would have

$ \binom{5} {0} + \binom{5} {1} +  \binom{5} {2} +  \binom{5} {3} +  \binom{5} {4} +  \binom{5} {5} = 1+5+10+10+5+1$

Comment: except that $\binom{5}{0}$ refers to no symptoms, so you do not want to count it.

Answer (score 3):

Each repulsive symptom is either there or not, independently.  So there are $2^5$ different lists. Leaving out the lucky one with no symptoms, that leaves 31 possibles.

PS.  You've missed some in your list, and double counted others...

There are 5 possible single-symptom lists.  It can be recycled as the missing symptom list, so there are 5 4-symptom lists as well.

For two symptoms, there are 5 first symptoms combined with 4 second symptoms, giving 20, or rather 10 because you've counted them all twice.  That makes 10 three-symptom lists as well, and finally 1 with all 5

Answer (score 1):

To find the number of combinations of $r$ symptoms, the answer sure is $\binom{5} {r}$. If you want all of the combinations, you sum through $r= 1, 2, \dots, 5$. As a special case to the [Binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) we have  $\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} = (1+1)^n = 2^n$, thus in your case, where $n=5$ and the case of no symptoms is excluded, we get $2^5 - 1 = 31$ combinations.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't taken a combinatorics class thus far, but the question you are asking is "What are all of the potential combinations?"

You have answered your own question here by listing all potential combinations. Maybe I miss the point here.

edit: A general formula that encompasses many situations in math would be (desired outcome)/(all possible outcomes).

Comment: Yes, how to generalize, what is the general formula and why?

Comment: You can look at it like so: P(one symptom) = 5; P(two symptoms)= 11; P(three symptoms) = 6; P(four symptoms) = 2; P(all)=1;                                                         Now, assuming I understand the question you're asking, you can apply an axiom of probability theory "mn outcomes", given that there are m = 5 cases and n = sum(5 x 11 x 6 x 2). Hope this helps.